# Why initialized variable is not visible after comment line?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, typedef

error message is: **error: ‘basicInfo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     basicInfo->errorlog = malloc(VAL_SZ);**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <string.h> //strdup

#define VAL_SZ 64

typedef struct {
    char* errorlog;
    char* cache_size;
    char* cache_replacment;
    int timeout;
} basicInfo_t;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //-------------BASIC INFO SETUP-------------\\
    basicInfo_t* basicInfo = malloc(sizeof(basicInfo_t));
    basicInfo->errorlog = malloc(VAL_SZ);
    basicInfo->cache_size = malloc(VAL_SZ);
    basicInfo->cache_replacment = malloc(VAL_SZ);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you used a `\\` at the end

```
//-------------BASIC INFO SETUP-------------\\
```

Tells the compiler to continue the statement onto the next line.
Thus, the line

```
basicInfo_t* basicInfo = malloc(sizeof(basicInfo_t));
```

is actually not visible to the compiler (= commented out).

Remove the `\\` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have been too clever with your comment formatting.  A backslash character as the last on a source line makes the next line a continuation -- the backslash and immediately following line terminator are completely ignored.  This happens very early in source processing, before comments are recognized as such.

Because the preceding comment line ends with a backslash, the line on which you (mean to) declare variable `basicInfo` is actually part of the comment.  Therefore, there is indeed no actual declaration of that variable.  Just delete the two backslashes at the end of the comment, or perhaps add a blank line after it.

The syntax highlighting in my editor accounts for this, by the way.  I don't know about your editor, but if it doesn't do the same then one that is more clueful might be a help to you.